# How do I make get-iplayer produce watchable quality without huge filesize?

Tags: files, size

Summary findings:

1. I'm using get-iplayer v2.82. The files I produce on hard drive are all mp4.
2. I've discovered the following (downloading same TV program in both cases): Using `--modes=flashstd` and `--tvmode=flashhigh2`  gives a watchable quality file
   which is the *same filesize* as the qualities above this that `--modes` and `--tvmode`
   can deliver.

   The VERY NEXT step down in quality from the above settings (from my
   experimenting) is
   `--modes=flashstd` and `--tvmode=flashstd1`. This gives a smaller
   filesize, but is *NOT* a watchable quality.

   The point being that you don't seem to be able to drop down from a "too big" filesize to a smaller size and retain watchable quality.
3. My command line had the following form:
   `get-iplayer --get 1234 --modes=flashstd --tvmode=flashhigh2`

   I tried:

   i)  `--modes=flashstd --tvmode=flashhigh2`

   Result:  Filesize 170Mb (too big for my liking).
   (TV program: "The Slammer" from BBC iplayer, 30 minute duration, *watchable quality*.)

   ii) `--modes=flashstd --tvmode=flashstd1`

   Result:  Filesize 110Mb (an *acceptable size*, but *NOT* watchable quality).
   (TV program: Same program as above, from BBC iplayer, 30 minute duration, *NOT*
   watchable quality (some murky pixelation)).

   iii) For comparison: 
   TV program: "Terry and June", from YOUTUBE, mp4, only 90Mb filesize
   (ACCEPTABLE), 30 minutes duration, WATCHABLE QUALITY.

---

Full Details:

1. My aim is to avoid downloading files with get-iplayer that are twice as big
   as similar-duration programs that I download from youtube. You see I don't want
   to swallow up disc space.
2. I've deduced the following:

   `--modes`:
   Specifies the *recording quality* you want (in your file on the hard drive). For
   example, if you had a video tape recorder, then LP (long play) recording mode
   is a lower recording quality than SP (standard play).

   `--tvmode`:
   Specifies the *quality* of TV program that you want to fetch from the BBC end (eg.,
   HD, SD, and the sub-qualities within these).
3. I've intelligently experimented with combinations of `--modes` and `--tvmode`,
   but at the point at which a *smaller file* is produced, its quality isn't good
   enough to watch.
4. When I download say a 30 minute TV program from youtube, the filesize is say
   90Mb (mp4), and of watchable quality. But with get-iplayer (downloading from
   BBC), for the same program duration of 30 minutes, I can't produce a file that
   is less than about 170Mb  *AND* that is of watchable quality.